# How to search for a file that contains a specific "keyword: string" pair and print its whole contents using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I was given a project to make a project to store book records in a directory on different files.

If the user want to search a book by its name or author ,I wanted to search files in a directory to find a string matching with a key word and print the whole file using awk.
and if the user wanted to delete the file i wanted to delete it.
I tried to do the searching part with the following code but it only prints the line not the whole contents of file.

Records directory contains 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt ...

Example

```
  1.txt     

       author: jhon
       title :  book1
       year  : 2000
       pages : 342
```

I would appreciate it someone helps me out.

```
#!bin/bash
BOOK=./Records/*.txt
    # Ask the user what to look for.
        echo -n -e "What field would you like to search author or title: "
        read field

        echo -n "In the field = \"$field\", what string should I find? "
        read string 

        # Find the string in the selected field
        case $field in  

            "author" ) # Search for a specific name
                     awk -v var=$string -F ":" '$2~ var {printf "Record: %d\n\t%s\n\t%s\n\t%s, %s, %s\n\t%s\n", NR=1 , $1, $2}' $BOOK 

                     ;;

            "title" ) # Search for a specific name
                       awk -v var=$string -F ":" '$2 ~ var {printf "Record: %d\n\t%s\n\t%s\n\t%s, %s, %s\n\t%s\n", NR, $1, $2 }' $BOOK                     
                 ;;
            "*" ) # Search pattern not recognized
                  echo "I did not understand your field name";
                  ;;
        esac


        exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the full replacement of the script but just the idea you can extend

```
...
case "$field" in  
      author) # Search for a specific name
            grep -lF "author: $search_string" $BOOK | xargs cat
```

search literal string in files and print the filename of matches, pipe to cat to print the contents of the files...